# Boto rds.get_all_dbinstances returning empty list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds

I'm trying to obtain a list of all my AWS RDS instances using Python's Boto module. I can obtain the instance metadata fine which I then read into the connection to utilise `get_all_dbinstances()` but keep getting [] returned.

```
from boto.utils import get_instance_metadata
import boto.rds

# This works fine    
m =  get_instance_metadata()

access_key = m[****]
secret_key = m[****]
security_token = m[****]

try:
# And this works fine
    region_object = boto.rds.connect_to_region("eu-central-1", aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)

except ValueError, e:
    print "Error: {0}".format(e.message)

rds = boto.connect_rds(aws_access_key_id = access_key, aws_secret_access_key = secret_key, security_token = security_token, region=region_object.region)
instances = rds.get_all_dbinstances()
print instances

>> []
```

Answer (score 3):

The call to `connect_to_region` actually returns an `RDSConnection` object for that region so your code should really look like this:

```
rds = boto.rds.connect_to_region('eu-central-1', ...)
instances = rds.get_all_dbinstances()
```

Your original code is ignoring the region part and just getting a connection to the default region (`us-east-1`) where you obviously have no DB instances running.

Comment: Thanks for that, turned out to be a region issue, I'm based in Ireland so my region is eu-west-1 and not eu-central-1